# LINQ select new model without need of typing every parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

is it possible in LINQ to get all properties from two tables into new ViewModel without listing PersonId, Email and so on.

```
var person = (from o in db.Persons
                         join od in db.OsobeDetails on o.PersonId equals od.PersonId
                         where o.PersonId == id
                         select new PersonViewModel
                         {
                             PersonId= o.PersonId,
                             Email = o.Email
                         }).ToList();
```

something like:

```
... select new PersonViewModel();
```

I tried this but I don't get any results back. "id" is input parameter into method.

Comment: This is what AutoMapper was made for.

Answer (score 3):

You could have an override of your `PersonViewModel` constructor that takes a `Person` object, and set the properties there.

For example, if you had this constructor:

```
class PersonViewModel
{
    public PersonViewModel(Person person)
    {
        this.PersonId = person.PersonId;
        this.Email = person.Email;
        // ... other properties set here
    }
}
```

Then you could just do:

```
var person = (from person in db.Persons
    join od in db.OsobeDetails 
    on person.PersonId equals od.PersonId
    where person.PersonId == id
    select new PersonViewModel(person))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for answers. Didn't have time to test it properly. Sorry for missleading you, I need properties from both entites. When I tried this method, MVC gives me YSOD with error "Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities"

Answer (score 0):

This returns both entities o and od:

```
var person = (from o in db.Persons
              join od in db.OsobeDetails on o.PersonId equals od.PersonId
              where o.PersonId == id
              select new { Persons = o, OsebeDetails = od }).ToList();
```

access it something like:

```
person.Persons.PersonID
```

or

```
person.OsebeDetails.PersonID
```

or any other existing property.

Comment: Is that only solution. Because this way is selected anonymous object or two separate objects Persons and OsobeDetails, not PersonViewModel. That will produce problems with model binding

Comment: @croatum but have to somehow decide which properties you take from your different entities...

Comment: In the example, he was only taking properties from one entity. The other entity was just used to filter the set.